# WD MyBook 3TB - Gparted failed & HDD partitions recovery?

Tags: partition, usb, data-recovery, fdisk, parted

I have this new WD MyBook external HDD (USB 3.0/2.0); I created 3 partitions, all of them ext3 type (~1 TB | ~1 TB | ~750 GB)

I loaded lots of files all the partitions were like ~30% full on each, and on all my systems had problems with the HDD (same problem) the disk was recognized, mounted and I can work with it for several minutes/hours but then the HDD got disconnected and sometimes reconnected automatically.

So I grow tired of the above, but found no solution on the net nor my peers... so I figured out that one possibility was that the partitions were too large for my machines (all my systems are Linux and HW is 5 or more years old) thus I borrowed a new System 76 laptop and tested the drive on it, this machine had no problems loading the disk's partitions, none at all, that was when I realized that the problem were the huge partitions I've created and that my systems were unable to handle so I picked `gparted` using this laptop and resized the first partition of 1 TB to half its size.

The process took more than expected but finally `gparted` was on the last stage of the process; the last step was to ran `fsck` on both the new and the old partition, I waited two days but this process never completed, so I regretfully manually stopped the process and this is where hell started.

Now the disk is still recognized as an USB device:

```
kamino ~ # lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63f1 Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 005 Device 019: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 048: ID 1058:1130 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 009: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
kamino ~ #
```

But `fdisk` does not see anything connected nor `testdisk`... other than the machine's HDD.

When the drive is connected, the following chunk of log is generated on `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jan 26 23:30:02 kamino kernel: [328391.764238] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device number 47 using ehci_hcd
Jan 26 23:30:02 kamino kernel: [328392.027254] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
Jan 26 23:30:04 kamino kernel: [328393.120042] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device number 48 using ehci_hcd
Jan 26 23:30:04 kamino kernel: [328393.823141] scsi85 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
Jan 26 23:30:04 kamino mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 48: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2"
Jan 26 23:30:04 kamino mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 48 was not an MTP device
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.981177] scsi 85:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1130     1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.981906] scsi 85:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.982646] sd 85:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.982726] ses 85:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.982775] ses 85:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.985520] ses 85:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x8000002
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.985523] ses 85:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.988270] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.989270] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.989274] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.993635] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.995637] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.995641] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino kernel: [328396.995644] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 26 23:30:07 kamino ata_id[20922]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdb'
```

And the information showed by `dmesg` is:

```
[328391.764238] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device number 47 using ehci_hcd
[328392.027254] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[328393.120042] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device number 48 using ehci_hcd
[328393.823141] scsi85 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[328396.981177] scsi 85:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1130     1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[328396.981906] scsi 85:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[328396.982646] sd 85:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[328396.982726] ses 85:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[328396.982775] ses 85:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[328396.985520] ses 85:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x8000002
[328396.985523] ses 85:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[328396.988270] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[328396.989270] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[328396.989274] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[328396.993635] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[328396.995637] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[328396.995641] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[328396.995644] sd 85:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

I been looking information using all the keyword combinations on many search engines, forums, etc. without luck.

If I fire up `gparted` it only sees the HDD of the system, when I fire up `Gnome Disk Utility` the disk is showed as an USB device and it seems that I can format it from there.

Here is a screenshot of the “Gnome Disk Utility”:

[image: screenshot of the “Gnome Disk Utility”]

I would like to recover at least the information in the partitions that were not resized. Is this possible?

What are my options?